# Enable webhook authentication kubelet api

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks

I am having trouble enabling webhook authentication for the kubelet API. My cluster is deployed with kubeadm. [This post is similar, but not the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855609/enabling-kubelet-server-bearer-token-authentication)

I can authenticate to my API server with a bearer token just fine:

```
curl -k https://localhost:6443/api --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

I cannot authenticate against the kubelet api with the same header. I have enabled the following on the API server:

```
--authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
--anonymous-auth=false
--runtime-config=authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1=true,authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1=true
```

The following is enabled on the kubelet node(s) (via /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml)

```
address: 0.0.0.0
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
  webhook:
    cacheTTL: 2m0s
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
  webhook:
    cacheAuthorizedTTL: 5m0s
    cacheUnauthorizedTTL: 30s
```

Despite this, I get a "403 forbidden" when curling the /metrics endpoint on the kubelet. Something to note, I can perform the same API call against a cluster deployed with KOPS just fine. I am not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Are you running your kubelet service with ```KUBELET_AUTHZ_ARGS=--authorization-mode=Webhook --authentication-token-webhook \
--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt``` argument?

Answer (score 2):

The 403 indicates you successfully authenticated (or you would have gotten a 401 error), the kubelet checked with the apiserver if you were authorized to access kubelet metrics (otherwise it would have just allowed it), it got a definitely response from the apiserver (otherwise you would have gotten a 500 error), and the apiserver indicated the authenticated user is not authorized to access kubelet metrics.

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/#kubelet-authorization for details about what permission needs to be granted to access various endpoints on the kubelet's API. For metrics, the `nodes/metrics` resource in the `""` apiGroup must be granted.